# Can couchbase be used as the underlying JobRepository for spring-batch?

Tags: spring-batch, couchbase

We have a requirement where we have to read a batch of a entitytype from the database, submit info about each entity to a service which will callback later with some data to update in the caller entity, save all the caller entities with the updated data. We thought of using spring-batch however we use Couchbase as our database which is eventually consistent and has no support for transactions.

I was going through the spring-batch documentation and I came across the Spring Batch Meta-Data ERD diagram here :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/index-single.html#metaDataSchema

With the above information in mind, my question is:
Can Couchbase be used as the underlying job-repository for spring-batch? What are the things I should keep in mind if its possible to use it? Any links to example implementations would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JobRepository` needs to be transactional in order for Spring Batch to work properly. Here is an excerpt from the [Transaction Configuration for the JobRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#txConfigForJobRepository) section of the reference documentation:

> The behavior of the framework is not well defined if the repository methods are not transactional.

Since Couchbase has no support for transactions as you mentioned, it is not possible to use it as an underlying datasource for the `JobRepository`.

Comment: You can get ACID compliance at the document level, so perhaps it's not so clear cut?

Comment: ACID compliance at the document level is not enough. Several methods in the [JobRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/SimpleJobRepository.java) involve multiple DAOs in the same transaction, like for example updating a job execution and its corresponding execution context which live in different tables. So you really need ACID across collections to guarantee consistency.

Comment: I actually thought of combining the metadata tables into one big document having the tables nested into each other and then implementing a custom jobrepository which would do the crud operations on the document. The document would look like 
{ BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
   {BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
      { BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS,BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT , 
        BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION {BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT}}. Each Job will have one corresponding document. Not sure how feasible is this and the effort required to do so. Any comments?

Comment: That's technically possible as soon as your non-relational model honors the job repository contract (which is clearly defined in its javadoc) as well as transaction semantics of the framework.

Comment: Last question, do you know any other batch processing frameworks that might support NoSQL db? or should I write my own :-(.

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, Spring Batch will probably add support for MongoDB (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2727) as MongoDB added support for  transactions across multiple collections [since v4](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions).